банк начисляет 13% годовых. На сколько сумма вклада увеличится через 7 лет? (это полное условие) с циклом for
банк начисляет 13% годовых. На сколько сумма вклада увеличится через 7 лет? (это полное условие) с циклом for


покажите ваши попытки.
вклад с капитализацией или нет ?
если ответ на 2) - да, то какой период начисления % (каждый месяц, год, день) ?


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

это полное условие Оно не полное. Формулировка "На сколько увеличится сумма" однозначно требует ответа в рублях (тугриках, прочее), во всяком случае в русском языке. Но без знания начальной суммы ответ дать невозможно.

@Akina, ответ в подобных случаях даётся в процентах: на Y процентов.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Потому я и говорю, что условие подкачало. Просто выражение "на сколько" требует ответа в абсолютных единицах. Было бы "на сколько процентов" - слова бы не сказал...

num = 1000 # сумма вклада
for i in range(7): # семь лет
    num = num * 1.13 # проценты
print('Сумма вклада', num)


Вы нехороший человек. Зачем делать за школьников домашнее задание? Какова цель?
